# How can there be three model isomorphism classes for this extended theory of unbounded dense linear orders?

Tags: model-theory

I want to show that the theory $$ T := DLO \cup \{ c_i < c_{i+1} \mid i \in \omega \} $$ has exactly three non-isomorphic countable models, where $DLO$ is the theory of unbounded dense linear orders.

I struggle to see why there is not just *one* countable model of $T$ up to isomorphism: Suppose $M$ and $M'$ are any two countable models of $T$. Then $M$ and $M'$ are also countable models of $DLO$; so $M$ and $M'$ are countable unbounded dense linear orders. Thus, by Cantor's Theorem, $M$ and $M'$ are isomorphic to each other.

Where is my mistake? Thanks!

Comment: There are models with an element $d$ with $d>c_i$ for all $i$, and there are models with no such element.

Comment: With your reasoning, you get an isomorphism between $M$ and $M'$, but this is an isomorphism in the language $\{<\}$, not in the language $\{<\}$ to which you add constants $c_i$'s.

Comment: And among the models with an element $d$ as in **Angina Seng**’s comment there are those in which $\{c_i:i\in\omega\}$ has a supremum and those in which it does not.

Answer (score 2):

You've shown that the *reducts* are isomorphic, but not the structures themselves.

Suppose I have languages $\Sigma\subseteq\Sigma'$. Then to each $\Sigma'$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ I can associate its **reduct** to $\Sigma$; this is the $\Sigma$-structure $\mathcal{M}_\Sigma$ with the same domain as $\mathcal{M}$ and the same interpretation on all the symbols in $\Sigma$ (so basically I just throw away the extra symbols).

Now you've argued (correctly!) that if $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}\models T$ then $\mathcal{A}_{\{<\}}\cong\mathcal{B}_{\{<\}}$. But that's not enough to conclude that $\mathcal{A}\cong\mathcal{B}$. While it's certainly true that $\mathcal{M}\cong\mathcal{N}\implies\mathcal{M}_\Sigma\cong\mathcal{N}_\Sigma$, the converse fails badly. For an easy example, take $\Sigma=\emptyset$, $\Sigma'$ any language not consisting of only constant symbols, and consider two nonisomorphic $\Sigma'$-structures of the same cardinality.

The point is:

> **Isomorphisms between reducts need not preserve the "forgotten" structure** - that is, the "$\Sigma'\setminus\Sigma$-part."

---

Of course, this only points out the error in your argument - it doesn't explain why in fact $T$ has exactly three countable models up to isomorphism. Towards that, let me describe **two** nonisomorphic countable models of $T$, and leave finding the third as an exercise:

- In both $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, the underlying set will be $\mathbb{Q}$ and $<$ will be the usual ordering.
- In $\mathcal{A}$ we'll have $c_n=n$.
- In $\mathcal{B}$ we'll have $c_n=1-2^{-n}$.

Now, what's the *third* possibility? *(HINT: it's sort of a mix between $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ ...)*

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful. The third one is something like $c_n = \pi - 2^{-n}$, right? :)

Comment: @Maxi That's exactly right: the three types of countable model correspond to unbounded sequence, convergent sequence, and bounded-but-not-convergent sequence. It's not hard to modify this to show that for every finite $n$ there is a complete theory in a countable language with exactly $n$ countable models up to isomorphism ... **except for $n=2$.** Hilariously, there is no complete countable theory with exactly two countable models up to isomorphism! This is [due to Vaught](http://www.logic.univie.ac.at/~vfischer/Michael_Zechner_thesis.pdf).

Comment: Incidentally, it's worth noting that there is a sense in which the two "bounded sequence" models are more similar to each other than either is to the "unbounded sequence" model. Let $M$ be the bounded-divergent-sequence model and $N$ the bounded-convergent-sequence model. Then there is an elementary embedding $j:M\preccurlyeq N$ such that any two distinct $a,b\in N$ have different types over $im(j)$ (basically, "$M$ has a copy which is dense in $N$"). By contrast, no such embedding from either $M$ or $N$ to the "unbounded sequence" model exists.

Comment: Follow-up: using the method discussed above, we can construct three non-isomorphic models of $T$: $\mathcal M_1$ where the interpretation of the sequence of $c_i$'s has no upper bound, $\mathcal M_2$ where it has an upper bound but no supremum, and $\mathcal M_3$ where it has a supremum. To finish the argument, we need to show that an arbitrary model $\mathcal M'$ of $T$ is isomorphic to one of $\mathcal M_1$, $\mathcal M_2$ or $\mathcal M_3$. [...]

Comment: [...] My idea is to define an isomorphism $f$ between $\mathcal M'$ and the corresponding model $\mathcal M \in \{\mathcal M_1, \mathcal M_2, \mathcal M_3\}$ by sending each $c_i^{\mathcal M'}$ to $c_i^{\mathcal M}$, and then defining $f$ on the remainder of its domain by using a back-and-forth method. My question is: Given that we can use that $DLO$ is $\omega$-categorical, is there an easier proof to show that any model of $T$ must be isomorphic to one of $\mathcal M_1, \mathcal M_2$ and $\mathcal M_3$, without invoking back-and-forth? Thanks!